# How to modify a word doc with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word

I have a word document like that :

[image: worddoc]

What I want is to modify as I wish the yellow text and always keep the same white text.

Th goal would be to tell Python to put "Name1,Name2,NAme3" as I wish in the script. Same for the date and all the yellow text.

And furthermore, output a word document with the text specified in the script.

Take the doc word as I show abov, modify the yellow text as many times as I would, and how I would like it to be and output the same word documnt (regarding the whit text) with yellow text specified.

I don't know if I'm clear ?

Comment: Manipulating Word with eternal program is not ideal but you can take a look to [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It's actually the best way to work with word template in python.

Comment: I was precisely checking this post. it's old but maybe ?

Comment: Probably its a bit old, But the library is still active.